# How to display text file in columns using bashscript in unix?

Tags: bash, unix, multiple-columns

I am making a bash script contact list system. This is what it prints out.

```
=================
Menu
=================

Enter 1 for Insert new contact
Enter 2 for Print current contact list
Enter 3 for Search contact list
Enter 4 for Exit

Enter your selection:
```

For "1" it ask for name, email, and phone and stores them for variables then stores them in a text file.

```
case "$answer" in
1) echo -e "Enter in a new contact name: \c"
    read name
   echo -e "Enter in new contact email address: \c"
    read email
   echo -e "Enter in new contact phone number: \c"
    read phone
   echo "$name, $email, $phone" >> contacts.txt ;;
```

For 2 is where I am having trouble.  I want to display the text in three columns so I can sort them by name, email, or phone number.  This is my code for case 2.

```
2) cat contacts.txt ;;
```

Obviously it only spits out:

```
Test Name, Test@data.com, 123-123-1234
Blank Data, Data@aol.com, 234-555-5555
```

I want it to read:

```
Name          Email          Phone
Test Name     Test@data.com  123-123-1234
Blank Data    Data@aol.com   234-555-5555
```

How would I do that?  And how would I be able to sort it later on?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat contacts.txt 
Test Name, Test@data.com, 123-123-1234
Blank Data, Data@aol.com, 234-555-5555
$ awk -F, 'BEGIN{printf "%-12s %-15s %-12s\n","Name"," Email"," Phone"} {printf "%-12s %-15s %-12s\n",$1,$2,$3}' contacts.txt
Name          Email           Phone      
Test Name     Test@data.com   123-123-1234
Blank Data    Data@aol.com    234-555-5555
```

*How it works:*

The `printf` statement allows custom formatting of output.  Above the format string `%-12s %-15s %-12s\n` was used.  Taking  `%-12s`, for example, the `12s` part means that we want to format a string to a width of 12 columns.  The minus sign means that we want that field left-justified.

Looking at each piece of the `awk` code separately:

- `-F,`

  This tells `awk` to use a comma as the field separator on each line.
- `BEGIN{printf "%-12s %-15s %-12s\n","Name"," Email"," Phone"}`

  The BEGIN block is executed before the first line of the file is read.  It is used here to print the header.
- `printf "%-12s %-15s %-12s\n",$1,$2,$3`

  `awk` implicitly loops through every line in the file.  For each line, we print out the first three fields as per the format statement.

Comment: I got syntax error with this solution 3}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                                                              ^ backslash not last character on line

Comment: @cryptoparty I just tried the code again and it runs fine for me.  Could you verify that you copy-and-pasted the exact command in the answer?  If still get the error, please let me know which OS, which shell, and which version of awk you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
echo "$name, $email, $phone" >> contacts.txt ;;
```

to

```
echo "$name,$email,$phone" >> contacts.txt ;;
```

and try this:

```
(echo Name,Email,Phone; cat contacts.txt) | column -s , -t
```